# Swift - what's big-o of String(text[..<index])

Tags: ios, swift, string, big-o

When I learned python big-O of string[:index] was O(index).

However I've read apple developer document and swift's String is bit different from other languages. And there's no any documents about big-O of making substring from existing `String`.

I got curious about big-O of `String(text[..<index])` in Swift so is there anyone who can tell me the big-O of `String(text[..<index])`

Answer (score 1):

`String` is a collection of characters under the hood and `String` conforms to `BidirectionalCollection`, which protocol declares the `subscript(bounds:)` function as a required method. This change was introduced as part of [SE-0163](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0163-string-revision-1.md) and implemented in Swift 4.

Looking at the [documentation of `String.subscript(bounds:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2943910-subscript), it states that this method has `O(1)` complexity.

Comment: String doesn't conform to `RandomAccessCollection` it conforms to `RangeReplaceableCollection`

Comment: You can check yourself [RandomAccessCollection conforming types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/randomaccesscollection)

Comment: I dont know where did you get that info that under the hood a String is an array of characters. Can you please post a reference (link)?

Comment: IMO if you need to get a Character out of a String the complexity is  O(n). **"Complexity: O(1) if the collection conforms to RandomAccessCollection; otherwise, O(n), where n is the length of the collection."**

Comment: **Random-access collections can move indices any distance and measure the distance between indices in O(1) time. Therefore, the fundamental difference between random-access and bidirectional collections is that operations that depend on index movement or distance measurement offer significantly improved efficiency. For example, a random-access collection’s count property is calculated in O(1) instead of requiring iteration of an entire collection.**

Comment: **Conforming to the RandomAccessCollection Protocol

The RandomAccessCollection protocol adds further constraints on the associated Indices and SubSequence types, but otherwise imposes no additional requirements over the BidirectionalCollection protocol. However, in order to meet the complexity guarantees of a random-access collection, either the index for your custom type must conform to the Strideable protocol or you must implement the index(_:offsetBy:) and distance(from:to:) methods with O(1) efficiency.**

Comment: @LeoDabus [SE-0163](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0163-string-revision-1.md) was the Swift Evolution proposal that made String conform to `Collection` in Swift 4. I was slightly incorrect, String is a collection of characters, not an array of characters. String conforms to `BidirectionalCollection`, from which it gets the `subscript(bounds:)` conformance, whose [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2943910-subscript) does state that its complexity is `O(1)`.

Comment: I am not not sure if it is O(1). It is stated there that only RandomAccessCollections are O(1). Swift conforming to BidirectionalCollection IMO doesn't mean it will be O(1). **Due to the change in internal implementation, this means that these operations will be O(n) rather than O(1). This is not expected to be a major concern, based on experiences from a similar change made to Java, but projects will be able to work around performance issues without upgrading to Swift 4 by explicitly typing slices as Substring**

Comment: Again AFAIR you can not stride a `String.Index`. It only conforms to `Comparable`, `Equatable`and `Hashable`